# Haskell different implementations of sequence_

Tags: haskell, monads

I tested following implementations of

```
sequence_' :: Monad m => [m a] -> m () 

sequence_'b [] = return ()
sequence_'b (m : ms) = (foldl (>>) m ms) >> return ()

sequence_'d [] = return ()
sequence_'d (m : ms) = m >> sequence_'d ms

sequence_'e [] = return ()
sequence_'e (m : ms) = m >>= \ _ -> sequence_'e ms

sequence_'g ms = foldr (>>) (return ()) ms
```

To test these I used following:

```
sequence_'e [putChar 'a', putChar 'b', putChar 'c']
```

and

```
sequence_'e [getChar, getChar, getChar]
```

The above tests worked. The first one put the value abc on the HUGS screen and the cursor returned to the next line.

The second one accepted three characters typed on the HUGS screen and the cursor returned to the next line.

Please suggest more tests which I could do to test these implementations of sequence_ (I guess this is a sequence Monad).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's usually good to check what happens with infinite lists in Haskell

```
sequence_ (repeat (putChar 'a'))
```

and with lazy monads like `Writer`

```
import Control.Monad.Writer
execWriter (sequence_ (repeat (tell "a")))
```

If my intuition is correct, you should see at least one difference between your implementations with these cases.

Oh, and just to correct your vocabulary. `sequence` is just a function (some would call it a "monadic function"). Here are some diagrams about where the actual monad is:

```
putChar :: Char -> IO   ()
                   ^^
                  monad

tell :: w -> Writer w   ()
             ^^^^^^^^
              monad

sequence_ :: (Monad m) => [m a] -> m ()
                    ^      ^       ^
                    +------+-------+
                          monad
```

Comment: I am using HUGS. I think this is Haskell 98.

Comment: I got following error when I tried import Control.Monad.Writer
thru a script.

ERROR file:{Hugs}\packages\mtl\Control\Monad\Reader.hs:47 - Haskell 98 does not support dependent parameters

Comment: Oh, try Control.Monad.Trans.Writer then I think. Trans is from transformers package, which doesn't use as many spooky features